# Deserialize json with placeholders using jackson ObjectMapper

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I want to deserialize json that contains placeholders using jackson ObjectMapper. Is there any simple way to do this?

e.g. the field repositoryRoot would be deserialized into ./repos/clean

```
{   
"datastore": {
      "name": "AnotherDataStore",
      "appRoot": ".",
      "repositoryRoot": "${datastore.appRoot}/repos/clean"
}
}
```